# Cloud Function error "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I recently started playing with cloud functions and I am getting this error:

```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
>     at exports.createPost.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/srv/index.js:15:37)
>     at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
>     at /worker/worker.js:825:24
>     at <anonymous>
>     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

and this is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');

const ALGOLIA_APP_ID = "";
const ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY = "";
const ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME = "Posts";

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
//const firestore = admin.firestore;

exports.createPost = functions.firestore
    .document('User/{UserId}/Posts/{PostsID}')
    .onCreate( async (snap, context) => {
        const newValue = snap.after.data();
        newValue.objectID = snap.after.id;

        var client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);

        var index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
        index.saveObject(newValue);
    });
```

The onCreate function triggers at the right time and the problem is just the error. I have done my research and couldn't figure it out. I hope I can get some help.

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Sorry closed it with the wrong question, but it this has been asked multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`onCreate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created) functions receive a `DocumentSnapshot` type argument as its first parameter.  It looks like your function is not actually expecting that.  Since you're trying to use a property called `after`, it looks like your code is expecting a `Change` type argument, which will never be the case for onCreate events.  `Change` type objects are delivered to `onUpdate` or `onWrite` events only so you can detect the before and after states of a document.

If you want the data from a newly created document in an onCreate type trigger, you should code like this:

```
exports.createPost = functions.firestore
    .document('User/{UserId}/Posts/{PostsID}')
    .onCreate( async (snap, context) => {
        const newValue = snap.data();
        // use the document properties of newValue here
```